# (Python3) How can I import a file in the upper level directory?

Tags: python-3.x, import

## How to import a file in the upper directory？

For example, I have these files:

```
(root directory)
 a.py

./src/
---b.py
```

How to import `a.py` in `b.py`?

I tried to write:

```py
# .\src\b.py
import a
```

But the result is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myOperations'`.

I don't want to put a `__init__.py` in the root directory. Is there another way?

Comment: My first language is not English. So maybe I didn't express my meaning well. Sorry for that. If you can't understand, leave a comment and I will try to express better.

Answer (score 1):

Use two dots to go two levels high for example;
from .. import a